# Redmine Wiki Links to "Next" and "Previous" Pages

Tags: hyperlink, automation, wiki, redmine, redmine-plugins

Is there a plugin or an easy (semi-automated) way of adding "Next" and "Previous" links to a Redmine wiki page that is part of a sequence of pages (in my case, it's for a sequential tutorial)?

I guess the core problem here is that wiki's are not generally designed for making multi-page tutorials or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no automagic way of doing this, there are to ways you could implement it,

**Link directly**

You could always link to a wiki page directly by it's name, like

```
[[Page_1]]
```

or decorate the page link with a description;

```
[[Page_1|< < Previous]]
```

Will show as [< < Previous](http://your-redmine-server.com/projects/foo/wiki/Page_1)

**Use Parent-Child relationships**

On a newly created page, goto Rename and choose a parent Wiki page. That willl display a breadcrumb bar allowing backwards navigation. The page(s) will also show as child page(s) if you want to list all Wiki pages on Index By Title.

Reference: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineWikis#Creating-sub-pages-parentchild-relationships

Comment: (Tips appreciated if there is some way of making a plugin for this as I need the feature myself)